# Arithmetic mean of a register in vhdl

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx, xilinx-ise, digital-logic

For a project I am currently working on, I am trying to take some inputs, store them in a register then find the arithmetic mean of the register. All of my inputs are 24-bits long. My registers are 4-inputs long therefore I simply remove the last 3-digits of the least-significant bits while dividing them by 4 in order to calculate the arithmetic mean, then simply add them.

mean is my `register(95 downto 0)` (4 x 24 = 96), and `mean_medium` is type `unsigned`.

When I code the following line

```
signal mean_medium : unsigned (23 downto 0) := (others => '0');
mean_medium <= unsigned(medium (95 downto 75)) +
               unsigned(medium (71 downto 51)) +
               unsigned(medium (47 downto 27)) +
               unsigned(medium (23 downto 3)) ;
```

I took the following warning:

> Width mismatch. mean_medium has a width of 24 bits but assigned expression is 21-bit wide.

Do you have any suggestions to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An error already is that you divide by four by shifting 3 bits. You only need to shift 2 bits.

But for correct/precise arithmetic you should *not* pre-shift the operants of that expression, as you lose precision due to trunctation. First add all the 4 full 24-bit values to one 26-bit output. Then shift-and-round the output. Example

```
signal mean_medium : unsigned (23 downto 0); -- redundant := (others => '0');
signal mean_temp : unsigned(25 downto 0);

mean_temp <=
    resize(unsigned(medium (95 downto 72)), mean_Temp'length) +
    resize(unsigned(medium (71 downto 48)), mean_Temp'length) +
    resize(unsigned(medium (47 downto 24)), mean_Temp'length) +
    resize(unsigned(medium (23 downto 0)), mean_Temp'length) +
    2; -- round factor

mean_medium <= shift_right(mean_temp, 2); --divide by 4
```

p.s. you could also combine this in one line, removing the necessity of `mean_temp`.

Answer (score 0):

I am making the assumption that you are using the `numeric_std` package.

In the `numeric_std` package, the `+` operator requires that the width of the sum be the same width as the widest of the operands. You operands are 21 bits wide, your sum is 24 bits wide. So, you need to make your operands 24 bits wide, too. You can do this using the `resize` function in `numeric_std`. In fact, this should be sufficient:

```
mean_medium <= resize(unsigned(medium (95 downto 75)),24) +
               unsigned(medium (71 downto 51)) +
               unsigned(medium (47 downto 27)) +
               unsigned(medium (23 downto 3)) ;
```

but you could also do this if you think it tidier:

```
mean_medium <= resize(unsigned(medium (95 downto 75)),24) +
               resize(unsigned(medium (71 downto 51)),24) +
               resize(unsigned(medium (47 downto 27)),24) +
               resize(unsigned(medium (23 downto 3)) ,24) ;
```

Or some variation on this is even better:

```
mean_medium <= resize(unsigned(medium (95 downto 75)),mean_medium'length) +
               unsigned(medium (71 downto 51)) +
               unsigned(medium (47 downto 27)) +
               unsigned(medium (23 downto 3)) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

two side of a equation should have same size, you can use resize function or you can use a 24-bit temporary signal and do like this:

`signal temp : std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
temp(23 downto 21) <= "000";
temp(20 downto 0) <= medium (95 downto 75);
mean_medium <= temp + ....`